# displaying unique row and ranking in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to display unique rows and rankings in SQL.

Here is my attempt at a SQL query:

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (COALESCE(s.rows, 0) / COALESCE(trgt.rows, 0) * 100) DESC) AS Ranking, 
    TM_Emp_Id, Territory, TM_Name,
    COALESCE(s.rows, 0) AS DeliveredCount,
    COALESCE(nd.rows, 0) AS NotDeliveredCount,
    COALESCE(trgt.rows, 0) AS Target
FROM
    tblEmployee e
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         EmpCode, SUM(MedToPCount) AS rows 
     FROM 
         tblMdcn 
     WHERE 
         Status = 'Delivered' 
     GROUP BY 
         EmpCode) s ON s.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         EmpCode, COUNT(*) AS rows 
     FROM 
         tblMdcn  
     WHERE 
         Status != 'Delivered' 
     GROUP BY 
         EmpCode) nd ON nd.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         EmpCode, CurrentTarget AS rows 
     FROM 
         tbl_Target) trgt ON  trgt.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
```

I am trying to calculate rank on the basis of percentage of  total sum of delivered by given target.(Something like this:`(a/b)*100`, the one who has highest percentage ranked first). I have to use `INNER JOIN` here.
And how do I handle when target or DelieveredCount is `0`(in this case he should be ranked last).

The result I am getting is like this:-

```
 Ranking  TM_Emp_Id   Territory TM_Name DeliveredCount  NotDeliveredCount   Target
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1      101        South     Bob        12               2                  20
    1      101        South     Bob        12               2                  20
    1      101        South     Bob        12               2                  20
    2      102        North     Alice       5               0                  23
    2      102        North     Alice       5               0                  23
    2      102        North     Alice       5               0                  23
    3      103        South     Joe         1               0                  15
    3      103        South     Joe         1               0                  15
```

I want to display result like this:-

```
Ranking    TM_Emp_Id    Territory   TM_Name DeliveredCount  NotDeliveredCount   Target
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1       101          South       Bob         12                2               20
   2       102          North       Alice        5                0               23
   3       103          South       Joe          2                0               15
```

Any suggestions or directions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please supply some sample data (by providing DDL and `INSERT` statements). It's good that we have your expected result set, but we don't have any data to work with to get your result.

Comment: @Larnu As I have shown you the results I am getting. It's a repeated values. Currently I am unable to provide you the INSERT Statements.

Comment: @Larnu Am I calculating the Ranking in right way? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you could greatly simplify your logic here with some conditional aggregation. I didn't test this because we don't have data or table structures for everything but this should be pretty close.

```
SELECT
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (COALESCE(sum(case when Status = 'Delivered' then MedToPCount else 0 end), 0)/COALESCE(sum(case when Status = 'Delivered' then MedToPCount else 0 end), 0)*100) DESC) AS Ranking
  , TM_Emp_Id
  , Territory
  , TM_Name
  , sum(case when Status = 'Delivered' then MedToPCount else 0 end) AS DeliveredCount
  , sum(case when Status != 'Delivered' then 1 else 0 end) AS NotDeliveredCount
  , COALESCE(trgt.rows, 0) AS Target
FROM tblEmployee e
LEFT JOIN tbl_Target trgt ON trgt.EmpCode = e.TM_Emp_Id
GROUP BY TM_Emp_Id
  , Territory
  , TM_Name
```

I have to ask why you use the tbl prefix for your tables. Here is a good discussion on that. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the group by to group the rows and get the Max value of a column, around the select you created.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Ranking, Territory, Max(DeliveredCount), Max(Target) -- etc...
FROM (SELECT ...) --Your select here
GROUP BY Ranking, Territory, TM_Name
```

Comment: Can you tell me that I am calculating the rank in right way. And what would I do if any of attribute is 0 say target or Count.

Comment: I am not sure if is the right way, but I think that those left joins may be the reason to replicate the results.